# HTML5 Input Validation images with CSS3

Tags: html, css, validation

I am currently working on an HTML5 form and using CSS3 for the styling. I have added CSS for input:required and input:valid and input:invalid to make an image get shown inside the text box.

Both the required and invalid CSS work fine but for some reason input:valid gets ignored and is just replaced with the same image as input:required.

Below is the CSS that I have used

```
input:required.fields, textarea:required.fields, select:required.fields
{
    background:url("images/asterix.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}


input:focus:required:invalid.fields, textarea:focus:invalid.fields, select:focus:invalid.fields
{
    background:url("images/error.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Both CSS sections above work fine without any problems but its the CSS below that for some reason is not working.

```
input:valid.fields, textarea:required:valid.fields, select:value.fields
{
    background:url("images/tick.png");
    background-position: right;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

In case it was to do with the image not being found I made the invalid image be the tick.png image and this worked fine but the valid section never seems to get called.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the following on my form:

```css
input[required]:invalid {
    background: #efdee0 url(../images/invalid.png) no-repeat center right;
}

input[required]:valid {
    background: #f3f8ed url(../images/valid.png) no-repeat center right;
}
```

but then my fields are all required (http://www.paul-ellis.co.uk/contact.htm)